# Accordion h2 open by link

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, css

using code from this [site](http://info.summit7systems.com/blog/how-to-create-dynamic-accordions-in-sharepoint-pages) i have added accordion to SharePoint page. 
Now i'm try to open certain part of accordion by link from external page.

I guess it  should be done with hash but unfortunately it doesn't work for me
Do you have any suggestions what should I do?

```
var hash = window.location.hash; 
$(hash).find('.h2').trigger('click');
```

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/Teh_n/3udf23k1/3/) with code